# matrix is all zero outsize the loop

Tags: loops, opencv, for-loop, matrix, reset

I have one matrix as "srcMat", of 700x1 size. I used the following command to give values to an empty matrix "dstMat":

```
cv::Mat dstMat ( srcMat.rows, srcMat.cols, srcMat.type() ); 

for ( int i = 0; i <  medianMat.cols ; i ++ )
{
   dstMat( cv::Range::all(), cv::Range( i*5+1, i*5+4 )).setTo(srcMat.at<int>(i));
}
```

But the problem here is: dstMat is all zero outside (after) the "for" loop, but inside the loop, it has exactly the value I want. What is the problem here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what is dstMat, medianMat and their sizes and values so that we can run the block and do testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that every time you try to select a range, you're working on a read-only value.
So you're losing all the values, and none of them gets it way to the real matrix.

As it is written in opencv documentation, the value returned from `operator()` is `const`, so you can't edit the matrix using the returned value:

> Mat Mat::operator()( Range rowRange, Range colRange) **const**

However, if you use the second mask argument of setTo you should have no problem:

> Mat& Mat::setTo(const Scalar& s, **const Mat& mask=Mat()**)

**EDIT**

I would use colRange for copying and selecting columns,
the following code works for me:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  cv::Mat dstMat ( 3, 12, CV_32S );

  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    dstMat.colRange(2*i,2*i+2).setTo(i);

  std::cout<< "Destination\n" << dstMat << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

check to see if it changes the matrix for you too

Comment: Dear Kamyar, thank you very much for your answer. I tried several times for using mask in "setTo", but failed. Do you have any example code or suggestion for how to use it? I am quite new to OpenCV. Thank you again. With regards.

Comment: creating masks needs much more code, you should put 1s in places you want to copy and 0s in places you don't want. I have edited my answer with a sample code with colRange that you may try to see if it works for you